# How is this implicitly creating a Pandas Series from a Dataframe without calling .Series()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

```
aapl_table = quandl.get('WIKI/AAPL') # API call to a data source, returns a dataframe object
aapl = aapl_table['Adj. Close']['2017'] # how does this implicitly create a series object?
```

I've tried searching for ways to create Series from Dataframe objects, but they seem to involve a call to `pd.Series()` which is not explicit in this code example.

I end up with a Series object `aapl` that extracts the `Adj. Close` column values from the `aapl_table` dataframe object, for all entries with year `2017`. Additionally the `name` of `aapl` is also set to `'Adj. Close'`.

How is this happening, and where is the documentation for this method of creating a Series from a Dataframe?

```
>>> aapl_table
              Open    High     Low  ...    Adj. Low  Adj. Close  Adj. Volume
Date                                ...                                     
1980-12-12   28.75   28.87   28.75  ...    0.422706    0.422706  117258400.0
1980-12-15   27.38   27.38   27.25  ...    0.400652    0.400652   43971200.0
1980-12-16   25.37   25.37   25.25  ...    0.371246    0.371246   26432000.0
1980-12-17   25.87   26.00   25.87  ...    0.380362    0.380362   21610400.0
1980-12-18   26.63   26.75   26.63  ...    0.391536    0.391536   18362400.0
...            ...     ...     ...  ...         ...         ...          ...
2018-03-21  175.04  175.09  171.26  ...  171.260000  171.270000   35247358.0
2018-03-22  170.00  172.68  168.60  ...  168.600000  168.845000   41051076.0
2018-03-23  168.39  169.92  164.94  ...  164.940000  164.940000   40248954.0
2018-03-26  168.07  173.10  166.44  ...  166.440000  172.770000   36272617.0
2018-03-27  173.68  175.15  166.92  ...  166.920000  168.340000   38962839.0

[9400 rows x 12 columns]
```

```
>>> aapl
Date
2017-01-03    114.715378
2017-01-04    114.586983
2017-01-05    115.169696
2017-01-06    116.453639
2017-01-09    117.520300
                 ...    
2017-12-22    175.010000
2017-12-26    170.570000
2017-12-27    170.600000
2017-12-28    171.080000
2017-12-29    169.230000
Name: Adj. Close, Length: 249, dtype: float64
```

```
>>> type(aapl_table)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
>>> type(aapl)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas Dataframe objects are collections of Series objects.

The first code snippet accesses the column `'Adj. Close'`, which is a Series object, and stores the rows whose `datetime` year match `2017` to a new Series object called `aapl`.

```
aapl_table = quandl.get('WIKI/AAPL') # API call to get data, returns dataframe
aapl = aapl_table['Adj. Close']['2017'] # accesses the 'Adj. Close' Series object in the dataframe
```

In this code example there's no call (explicit or implicit) to `pd.Series()` because the Dataframe object is already a collection of Series objects.

> *Can be thought of as a dict-like container for Series objects. The primary pandas data structure.*

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html

> *DataFrame | frame[colname] | Series corresponding to colname*

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your index is of date format and you are directly getting column with the year. if you want the result as dataframe try using filter method.

Comment: I'd like to understand where the implicit call to .Series() is happening. Do you have a pointer to some documentation I could read on it or an explanation? How does Python know to make `aapl` a Pandas Series object?